# Responsive design breaks after shrinking the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm trying to build a bootstrap design with nothing special but a few columns and some information. First of all, i'd like to know if my code is alright, because I can see that items are not going like column below column as it should be after seeing the page from the small devices. I'm actually feeling now pretty sad about this, because i'm so exhausted that I cannot fix it anymore. Trying, trying and trying, but no results. Maybe you can have a look at my code? (I'd like to add a snippet, but for proper results there is a full source which I added [here](https://failiem.lv/u/vz2hy339)

Another question, I need to setup the min-size where bootstrap starts wirking from 320px. Where could I do this?

`Fiddle` [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/djemm1996/tL33zjvb/2/)!

Comment: Add a piece of code instead as finding the place where u went wrong in a application is difficult

Comment: I'm not downloading a zip file to see the code.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at your code and it seems that your problem is mostly just a general misunderstanding of how bootstrap responsiveness works. I would suggest reading up on a bit more to get an idea of how it is used in practice. When you set all your columns to be the same size then you take away what makes bootstraps responsiveness useful. Try making it so as the screen gets smaller, the components get more columns such as

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-9 col-sm-12">...</div>
```

This will take a good amount of experimentation for it to look perfect! :)

Comment: Adding to this, bootstrap has **4** basic size levels: lg (e.g large desktop), md (e.g smaller desktops), sm (e.g tablets), and xs (e.g phones). The way bootstrap does it is make you define how many columns out of the 12 for each element you want for each size level. What OP was doing was not really responsiveness; the page must resize and rearrange to look good at **almost** (don't try smartwatches...) any size, while still being the same page.